# Exporting Images/Movies to Final Cut Pro X to apply LUTs

Tags: export, video, color, file-format, color-management

i want to export my blender renders (doesn't matter if videos or image sequences) to Final Cut Pro X to apply LUTs on it. Now I'm not quite sure which rendering and output settings give the best results to me respectively are meant to be used for this. I'd like to get media like produced by log modes of HDR cameras. Should I use "linear raw" in the color management or is "Filmic Log Encoding Base" the better choice? For the look I should choose "none" because the others give me results with already applied LUTs, right?

I hope you understand my problem and I apologize for the awkward explanation but I'm new to this color grading stuff and still on the very beginning of my journey.

Thanks for your help!

Best Regards,
Janek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to master for HDR displays, you'll need to start ideally from a scene referred encoding such as an EXR. This likely is a bit of a mess in FCPX if I had to wager, as most applications are mostly designed for display referred work.

LUTs are tricky things. That is, any LUT is designed for a very specific input and a very specific output. Trying to modify imagery with LUTs designed for other contexts is a bit of a messy ball of nightmare.

It is hard to offer any further help as the question lacks important details and context.

Comment: I notice that FCPX will work in REC 2020 for HDR if required https://support.apple.com/kb/PH26148?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US but many of the in built LUTs are designed for various camera LOG schemes. https://support.apple.com/kb/PH12685?locale=en_AU

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers! You really helped me a lot understanding LUTs and I think now I'm able to implement what I indented to do :)

Comment: @3pointedit REC.2020 isn't HDR. HDR standards use REC.2020 as the primaries, but not the transfer function which is dictated by ST.2084. As I said, I would wager that FCPX, much like all of the other display referred rubbish out there, will have to jump through hoops to make it deal with scene referred content appropriately.

Comment: I guess I should have said that Apple recommend their REC.2020 for HDR work.